# openjpa error while using eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, cloud, ejb-3.0

I am getting the below error , when I test my application on oracle cloud. I am using Eclipse link but the below error is indicating openjpa.

```
<openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1445923 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property.
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:72)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:776)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:553)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1250)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:505)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:430)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:103)
        at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
        at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:843)
        at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:834)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:638)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:183)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
        at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:199)
        at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:152)
        at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:56)
```

this is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="viamd" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
       <jta-data-source>weblogic.jdbc.jts.viamd</jta-data-source>    
    <class>com.intiqua.viamd.model.datamanipulation.DataAccountingUnitBean</class>
    <class>com.intiqua.viamd.model.datamanipulation.DataActionsBean</class>
    <class>com.intiqua.viamd.model.datamanipulation.DataActionsRoleBean</class>
    <class>com.intiqua.viamd.model.datamanipulation.DataAddressBean</class>
    <class>com.intiqua.viamd.model.datamanipulation.DataAdmitOrderMatrixBean</class>
    <class>com.intiqua.viamd.model.datamanipulation.DataAgeGroupBean</class>
    <class>com.intiqua.viamd.model.datamanipulation.DataAgeGroupBrandBean</class>
    <class>com.intiqua.viamd.model.datamanipulation.DataAOMatrixHospAssocBean</class>
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="FINEST" />
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="true"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="true"/>

    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am getting error while executing the below line of code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("viamd");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: so you are NOT using Eclipselink; can't get simpler. So then you work out why OpenJPA is being used ... for example, maybe you use some JavaEE container that has OpenJPA as the default and it found that ...

Comment: Thanks. but when I check in weblogic , it says that TopLink is the default JPA. other than checking in weblogic console how can we check the default JPA used in JavaEE Container.

Comment: what about the LOG? the root of all debugging. Also this version of OpenJPA is ANCIENT

Comment: Log is there ,it is showing openjpa error. but this problem is coming when I  deploy my project on oracle cloud, in my local instance I am not getting any open jpa error because I am not using open jpa at all.